# How to find the inverse of this function?

Tags: functions

$$f(x)=\frac{x+1}{2x+1}$$

In my math class theory note, the teacher said that the function should be bijective (one-to-one and onto) to exist an inverse function. He also stated that in order to find the inverse function first we should mathematically prove this function as a bijective. I did the proving of this being one-to-one, but i could not do this function being onto. Please help me out.

And also if this logic is not true tell me about that too

Comment: What is the domain and range of the function?

Comment: Well it is not given. If possible please use an appropriate range and a domain to clarify my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing a rough graph shows it's bijective.

[image]

Here is the graph for [$$f=\dfrac{x+1}{2x+1}$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=%28x%2b1%29/%282x%2b1%29)

so, it's bijective in $\Bbb R- \{-1/2\}\to \Bbb R-\{1/2\}$.

> You can draw it as follws:
>
> It is undefined at $x=-1/2$ and $f\to1/2$ as $x\to\pm \infty$ , also $x=-1$ is a root , and we can see the polarity of function by wawy curve method.

Now put $y=f(x)$ and find $x=g(y)$, so $g=f^{-1}$

$$y=\frac{x+1}{2x+1}$$
We get:$$x=\frac{1-y}{2y-1}=f^{-1}$$

Comment: It's not bijective in $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, it's not even defined everywhere.

Comment: @Silencer Oop's I meant to say in domain->range

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$y=\frac{x+1}{2x+1}\iff x(2y-1)=1-y\iff x=\frac{1-y}{2y-1}\ldots$$

But you must first be sure of the domain and range of the original function...

Comment: Indeed there was, thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Is it supposed to be **answer** instead of **Hints**.?

Comment: It's suposed to be whatever I want...and the OP *understands*.

Comment: Fair enough. :)